# KendoUI Grid inline edit: focus cell on doubleclick

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in inline edit mode to which I bound a dblclick event which enables the doubleclicked line for edit and should also focus on the cell which was targeted by the doubleclick.
I wrote the example in codepen, please see the following link:
http://codepen.io/kpax/details/IyFab/

When the doubleclick is performed in the first two cells it works as expected. But if it's performed on the last three cells, the focus is placed in the first cell.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot in advance for replies!

Comment: Pretty strange, can't really figure it out, but my gut feeling is the focus() runs before the row is done being placed in edit mode. An guly way to fix this is if you wrap the cell focus line in a setTimeout of 200 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the focus part of the grid's edit is async, so your focus works, but then the edit's focus takes place and you focus on the default (the first cell).
Here's a working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avApy
All I did was to wrap the focus line with setTimeout to make sure it happens after the edit command is over completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the amount of time it's taking the Kendo grid to change the formatting of the row. I was able to make this work with as little as a 10ms delay.

```
var timeout = 25;
setTimeout(function() {
    cell.find("input").focus();
}, timeout);
```

But even 50 or 100 ms did not produce a noticeable delay. It just has to be enough time for the browser to process the script that turns the normal row into an editable one (I think).